# A better bound for FKMO 2015 P3

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple graph with at least three vertices and a path of length $L$. Prove that if $G$ is 2-connected, there exists a cycle of length at least $2\sqrt{L}$

The original problem ask for $\sqrt{2L}$. But on AoPS, a member sated that one contestant prove it for $2\sqrt{L}$. I did not attemp to solve the problem in this case, so I don't think that I would be able to make any statement about it.

Original thread: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1065216

Comment: Any idea for this bound?